# GetWindowLongPtr sets Error to "Class already Exists"

Tags: c++, winapi, wrapper

In my Windows API wrapper, I can choose to have a message box come up when there's an error. I have one that I can't really pin down though.

Here's my main function:

```
int main()
{
    Window win; //create default window with default class (name changes each new instance)

    return messageLoop(); //the familiar GetMessage() while loop, returns msg.wParam
}
```

This all works fine, but when I close my window (just tested via X button), I get the following message (this is what I get when I copy the message box):

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
File: "G:\programming\v2\wwbasewindow.h"
Function: _fakeWndProc
Line: 61
Error Code: 1410
Error: Class already exists.


---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Now it's crystal clear where this error is coming from, but not exactly why. Here's the `_fakeWndProc` function. The whole `wrap (function, args)` syntax checks `GetLastError()` after that function is called. This is why you don't see error checking.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK BaseWindow::_fakeWndProc (msgfillparams) //trick procedure (taken from someone's gui wrapper guide)
{
    BaseWindow * destinationWindowPtr = 0; //for which window message goes to

    //PROBLEM IN THE FOLLOWING LINE (gets a pointer to the window, set when it's created)
    destinationWindowPtr = (BaseWindow *)wrap (GetWindowLongPtr, hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

    if (msg == WM_COMMAND && lParam != 0) //if control message, set destination to that window
        destinationWindowPtr = (BaseWindow *)wrap (GetWindowLongPtr, (hwin)lParam, GWLP_USERDATA);

    if (destinationWindowPtr) //check if pointer is valid
        return destinationWindowPtr->_WndProc (hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam); //call window's procedure
    else
        return wrap (DefWindowProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam); //call default procedure
}
```

I'm just wondering why this call is (trying to create a class?) That aside, I tried checking the error codes from the time a `WM_CLOSE` message comes along. I output the code before the line, and after. This is what comes up:

```
Before: 0
After: 0
--->Before: 0
--->Before: 1410
After: 1410
Before: 1410
After: 1410
...
```

This puts the topping on my confusion, as this implies that the function calls `SendMessage` somewhere inside. But why wouldn't it do the same for any others?

The error itself doesn't make much of a difference, as the program ends right after, but I don't want it hanging around. How can I deal with it?

Note:
I just tried not calling `PostQuitMessage (0);` when `WM_DESTROY` came up, and created 2 windows. Both of them gave the same error when closing, so it's not necessarily the end of the program anyways.

Also, each one gave an error 1400 (Invalid window handle) too, but only when I didn't call `PostQuitMessage`. This error originated from the call to `DefWindowProc` in those windows' respective window procedures. Any ideas on that one either?

Edit:

Due to request, here is the code for `wrap`:

```
// pass along useful error information (useless constants within error function)
#define wrap(...) Wrap (__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

// cstr == char *
// con == const
// sdword == int (signed dword)

// version if return value of API function is not void
template<typename TRet, typename... TArgs>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<TRet>::value, TRet>::type
Wrap(con cstr file, const char * const func, con sdword line, TRet(*WINAPI api)(TArgs...), TArgs... args)
{
    TRet result = api(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...); //call API function
    if (GetLastError()) __wwError.set (GetLastError(), file, func, line); //set variables and create message box
    return result; // pass back return value
}

// version if return value is void
template<typename... TArgs>
void Wrap(con cstr file, const char * const func, con sdword line, void(*WINAPI api)(TArgs...), TArgs... args)
{
    api(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    if (GetLastError()) __wwError.set (GetLastError(), file, func, line);
}
```

I'm 100% sure this and `__wwError.set()` work though. All other functions wrapped with this give appropriate message boxes.

Comment: can you please show the code for wrap?

Comment: wrap should be working fine, but it's a bit of a this>that>this>that type of thing. I'll work on putting it in.

Comment: I just want to check that you are calling GetLastError **only** when then API call fails.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any evidence that DefWindowProc uses SetLastError. I trust you aren't making that very common mistake.

Comment: I didn't spend too much time with that one, but I'll check what the error is before and after like I did with the other one.

Comment: Capturing when the error changed from before to after the `DefWindowProc` call provided me with `0>1410, 0>1410, 0>1400` consecutively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your calls to GetLastError are simply incorrect. You cannot indiscriminately call GetLastError like that. You should only call it when the API call documentation says that it is valid to do so. Usually this will be if the API call reports failure.

The calls to DefWindowProc are a fine illustration of how this can go wrong. The documentation for DefWindowProc does not make any mention of a way for the function to report failure. And it makes no mention of calling GetLastError. Thus your calls to GetLastError should not be made and are returning undefined, meaningless values.

Since there is no single common mechanism for a Win32 function to report failure, your attempt to wrap all Win32 API calls with a single common error handling routine is doomed to failure.

What you need to do is to treat each API call on its own merits, and write error checking appropriate for that API call. Since you are using C++ I would recommend you make use of exceptions here. Write a function, ThrowLastWin32Error say, that you call whenever an API function reports failure. The implementation of ThrowLastWin32Error would call GetLastError and then call FormatMessage to obtain a textual description before throwing a suitably descriptive exception. You would use it like this:

```
if (!CallSomeWin32Function())
    ThrowLastWin32Error();
```

But the main point is that you do need case-by-case checking of function success since different Win32 functions report failure in different ways.

Comment: While `DefWindowProc` may not say anything about calling `GetLastError` (and yes, I guess I'll remove that one then), `GetWindowLongPtr` does. I can distinguish whether to call `GetLastError` or not by either using `foo (a)` or by using `wrap (foo, a)`. In the future, for other types of errors, I can just make the template have a specific action depending on the type of error it is. Instead of just `wrap`, I could use `win32error`, `dxerror`, `socketerror`, or whatever situation it is. I'll go through the ones I wrap now though and remove the unnecessary calls.

Comment: It's more complex than that. Even when GetLastError is the mechanism, it's only meaningful to call GetLastError if the function **failed**. There are lots of ways for a function to report failure. Don't call GetLastError unless the function fails and the documentation for that function says that you can call GetLastError.

Comment: My bone to pick against exceptions is that you have to try-catch them every single time there could be an error. Surrounding the call is a lot less writing and feels a lot less repetitive. I do see how they work well, being able to throw anything and you being able to handle what want, but it's simply a lot to add in for every call I make.

Comment: I think there is universal agreement that exception based error handling is easier to code against than error code based handling. In a Windows program you generally only need a top level handler to catch all exceptions. It's up to you whether or not you use exceptions but no matter what, you can't blanket wrap win32 API error checking as you hoped. Sadly win32 errors are much more tricky than, say, COM errors.

Comment: Isn't the action if a function doesn't fail to call `SetLastError (0);` though (if it tells you to check `GetLastError`)? An error of 0 is basically discarded (it still syncs the variables) when passing it into the class as an error.

Comment: No. Only call GetLastError if the function fails. They don't all call SetLastError(0).

Comment: Well, what if I used the exception approach, but instead of throwing an exception, I pass along the appropriate error? I'd still be doing that in the exception handler, but this would do it for me (and the boxes only come up if I define something too, so they are more of a debugging thing).

Comment: This is clearly indicated in the docs for SetLastError. *Most functions call SetLastError or SetLastErrorEx only when they fail. However, some system functions call SetLastError or SetLastErrorEx under conditions of success; those cases are noted in each function's documentation.*

Comment: This would still work if you did `Wrap(){ ret = api(); if (!ret) //error; return ret; }` wouldn't it?

Comment: No. Not all functions use a BOOL return value. Not all functions cal SetLastError at all.

Comment: If they don't say to use `GetLastError` I just won't put it into `wrap`. If it doesn't follow any behaviour defined in `wrap` I can always deal with it without using `wrap`.

Comment: I don't understand all the debate that's going on in the comments here. The documentation makes everything David is saying *quite* clear. It does pay to read it. Don't call `GetLastError` unless A) the docs specifically say that to do so, and B) the function returns a failure code.

Comment: I don't mean for it to be a debate. I'd still be following these rules if I implemented the small workarounds of general BOOL returns by calling wrap, handling any non-BOOL returns without calling wrap, and just calling the function normally without error checking when it doesn't say to use GetLastError. I'm just trying to figure out what's wrong with each new approach.